# from eregi to preg_match

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I've upgraded my php to 5.3 so i need to change regex expressions to preg_match. I've successfully made few changes to a script using delimiters and changing regex to preg_match but i'm struck with the following code which i tried to change in the following way though i didn't get any error cookies are not getting deleted.

```
if (preg_match('#COOKIE_PREFIX#i', $key))
```

Original code is

```
   // destroys the session cookies
function destroy($hash)
{
    foreach ($_COOKIE as $key => $value)
    {
        if (eregi(COOKIE_PREFIX, $key))
        {
            $key = str_replace(COOKIE_PREFIX, '', $key);
            xtsetcookie($key, '');
        }
    }
    $this->userinfo['user_id'] = 0;
}
```

P.S: The script developer is not replying to my support requests....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since `COOKIE_PREFIX` is a constant defined to have some value you *should not be enclosing it in quotes*. Instead try:

```
if (preg_match('#'.COOKIE_PREFIX.'#i', $key))
```

this would fail if `COOKIE_PREFIX` contained a `#` in it, so better use:

```
if (preg_match('#'.preg_quote(COOKIE_PREFIX,'#').'#i', $key))
```